# Hibernate dropping session while looping on a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got this exception `LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session` while looping on a collection of `MyTable`. e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "key", referencedColumnName = "key_from_other_table",
        updatable = false, insertable = false
    )
    private List<OtherTable> objects;
    public List<OtherTable> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }
    public void setObjects(List<OtherTable> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }
}
```

Then in an ordinary for loop

```
for (MyTable myTable : collectionOfMyTables) {
    myTable.getObjects();
}
```

exception will occur when the loop reaches the 3rd `myTable` where it has the same value in the column "key_from_other_table" with any previous `myTable` in the `collectionOfMyTables` collection.

No exception occur if all `myTable` objects have different value in the column "key_from_other_table".

e.g.:

```
MY_TABLE
id | key_from_other_table | some_values
---------------------------------------
 1 | SET_A                | xxx
 2 | SET_B                | yyy
 3 | SET_C                | zzz

OTHER_TABLE
id | key   | more_values
------------------------
 1 | SET_A | xxx_1
 2 | SET_A | xxx_2
 3 | SET_B | yyy_1
 4 | SET_C | zzz_1
 5 | SET_C | zzz_2
```

The above would have no exception.

```
MY_TABLE
id | key_from_other_table | some_values
---------------------------------------
 1 | SET_A                | xxx
 2 | SET_B                | yyy
 3 | SET_A                | zzz

OTHER_TABLE
id | key   | more_values
------------------------
 1 | SET_A | xxx_1
 2 | SET_A | xxx_2
 3 | SET_B | yyy_1
 4 | SET_C | zzz_1
 5 | SET_C | zzz_2
```

The above caused exception when reading the 3rd `myTable`.

But given same key value is allowed in MY_TABLE (i.e. multiple MyTable entities can share same objects from OtherTable), how do you fix this?

I heard changing the fetch mode to eager may resolve this, but I would prefer a solution that is using lazy fetch, thank you.

Comment: LazyInitializationException happen because hibernate's Session is close when a lazy loading is triggered but the cause can comes from many reason. Could you add some details ? Like the defintion of the relation on OtherTable.class, how you open and close the Session and if you have some kind of logics in the for loop.

Comment: @BaptisteBeauvais Thanks. Do you think it could be the annotation `OneToMany` but really my data can be ManyToMany?

Answer (score 1):

First off, for a OneToMany association, the SQL table for the 'many' side (i.e. OtherTable) should have a foreign key that points to the primary key of the 'one' side (i.e. MyTable). In your case, that would mean OtherTable should have a column named something like 'myTableId' that points to 'id' in MyTable.

This would result in an ORM as such:

```
class MyTable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "myTableId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<OtherTable> otherTables;
}
```

But since you state that a single OtherTable can be a member of multiple MyTables, you need a ManyToMany association. This involves creating a Join Table. The join table might be called MyTableOtherTable_JT. This table would have two foreign key columns, one that points to the primary key of MyTable, named myTableId, and another column that points to the primary key of OtherTable, named otherTableId.

This would result in an ORM as such:

```
class MyTable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "MyTableOtherTable_JT"
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "myTableId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "otherTableId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    List<OtherTable> otherTables;
}

class OtherTable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed info. I would imagine the setup didn't quite fit the usage. I will change it but do you think it was the different use of annotations caused the exception I saw?

Comment: It probably had something to do with the fact that you were treating the association as a OneToMany instead of ManyToMany. In which case I imagine that hibernate was expecting to have to lookup the object from the database, but the object was already within its persistence context (from the first time it was loaded), which may have resulted in your exception. Don't quote me on this though :).

Comment: Thanks again. So I understand your extra join table is the proper way to do it, but is there a way to solve my question without the join table, i.e. only the two tables? I have added examples in the question to illustrate the data.